# Trouble starting up a certain program (apfel)

Tags: python, readline

I'm trying to get this program apfel to run on my Ubuntu 20.04. I believe I have installed it successfully. When I run `apfel` in the terminal, I got the following error message:

```
File "/usr/local/bin/apfel", line 12
    print "Module readline not available."
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Module readline not available.")?
```

This is the content of the program apfel in usr/local/bin:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os
import inspect
#from lhapdf import *
import apfel

try:
    import readline
except ImportError:
    print "Module readline not available."
else:
    import rlcompleter
    readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")

def apfelhelp():
    print "Available apfel functions:"
    print dir(apfel)

from apfel import *

#red color
r = "\033[31m"

#whie color
w = "\033[0m"

#clear the terminal
os.system('clear')

print "\nWelcome to "
print "     _/_/_/    _/_/_/_/   _/_/_/_/   _/_/_/_/   _/"
print "   _/    _/   _/    _/   _/         _/         _/"
print "  _/_/_/_/   _/_/_/_/   _/_/_/     _/_/_/     _/"
print " _/    _/   _/         _/         _/         _/"
print "_/    _/   _/         _/         _/_/_/_/   _/_/_/_/"
print "_____v", GetVersion(),"A PDF Evolution Library, arXiv:1310.1394"      
print "     Authors: V. Bertone, S. Carrazza, J. Rojo"
print "\n Type apfelhelp() for help\n"


EnableWelcomeMessage(False)

#custom prompt
sys.ps1 = r + "[apfel]: " + w
os.environ['PYTHONINSPECT'] = 'True'
```

As I understand it the program starts up python first, then run `import readline`, it is not successful and thus try to print the error message, but got the error because of the lack of parentheses.

However when I start up python myself (I have python 3 I believe) and type in `import readline` I encounter no issues. Can anyone see where the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

The program you are trying to run is a python script. It should be coded according to the correct syntax. `print "Module readline not available."` is not valid syntax in Python 3. It should read `print("Module readline not available.")`.

Either correct the code yourself, or file an issue to the developper.